# What is Association[Rule["ID",number ] and how it is used?

Tags: dataset, associations

I am trying to understand the structure and the use of `Dataset` and I came across something new to me.

First check this example:

```
ds1=Dataset[{
  <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "c" -> 6|>,
  <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {2, 3}|>,
  <|"a" -> "x", "b" -> "z", "c" -> {3}|>,
  <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {4, 5}|>,
  <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {5, 6, 7}|>,
  <|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {}|>}]

ds2=Dataset[{
  <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "c" -> 6|>,
  <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {2, 3}|>,
  <|"a" -> "x", "b" -> "z", "c" -> {3}|>,
  <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {4, 5}|>,
  <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {5, 6, 7}|>,
  <|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {}|>}]
ds1===ds2
(*False*)
```

When I look at the `FullForm`, I found that each one has different  `Association[Rule["ID", number]` at the end of the `FullForm`. This number changes each time `ds1` or `ds2` are evaluated.

I have two questions:

1-If I have a big `Dataset` how can I know if they are equal or not?

2- What is `Association[Rule["ID", number]` and how it is used?

Comment: Ok. should I wait for someone to support your suggestion or I just go ahead and post separate questions?

Comment: Thanks:) I want to search each one separately.

Comment: They are not in the same association but in different associations in the same Dataset.

Comment: Done. Thanks:).

Comment: I'm puzzled.  Look at `TreeForm[ds1]` and then `ds1[[1]]`. How can you get the full list of data out of the dataset?

Comment: AtomQ[ds1] is True. It looks like ds1[[1]] is the same as ds1[1] which is an Query. Check this ds1[[2;;3]] and ds1[2;;3], same result.

Comment: Semantically, a `Dataset` is intended as a database table within Wolfram Language. As such, it should not be common practice to ask whether two `Dataset`s are the equal, much like one wouldn't ask whether two database tables are the equal.

Answer (score 4):

I'm interested in your question because I've never thought to look at the full form of a `Dataset` before! As such, I can't really say what the internal ID might be for in the `Dataset` object, except to say that `SameQ` likely fails because `Dataset` is likely treated internally like an Object. Each instantiation is distinct.

However, you can test for sameness of the data within a `Dataset` like so:

```
SameQ @@ (Normal /@ {ds1, ds2})
```

I hope at least that helps!